# Android desing support lib change the Tab indicator

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-tablayout

[image: **enter image description here**]

**Current there is no method to set drawable in tabindicator of TabLayout from design support lib.**
**Is there any other way to set drwable to tabindicator?**

Comment: tabSpec.setIndicator(view); ??

Answer (score 0):

**you will have to set the title values yourself**

see this code snippet:

```
public void setupTabLayout(TabLayout tabLayout) {
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewpager);

    TextView tab = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tab.setText("Library");
    tab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tabbar_library, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tab);
    //..
}
```

custom_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tab" />
```

maybe this help.

Comment: This way is it not possible.I need to set my drawable to indicator not to tab view.